# (Python) How to access/use variable from different method in class?

Tags: python, class, variables, methods

here's my code

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius = 1):
        self_radius = radius

    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle with radius {}".format(self_radius)
```

i took it from my teacher's slide, it took an integer (radius) when called (a = Circle(25) -for example) then return --Circle with radius 25-- when i print it

the problem is when i do that, instead getting it, i got an error saying that self_radius is not defined (in **str** method), so the question is how to use a variable in different method than it's origin?

Thank you

Comment: It's `.`, not `_`.

Answer (score 1):

Qualify instance attributes with `self.`, not `self_`:

```
class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, radius = 1):
        self.radius = radius

    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle with radius {}".format(self.radius)
```

If you name the variable `self_radius`, it become local variable; not accessible from another method.

Comment: i tried it and it's works! Thanks for it!

Comment: can you explain what kind of variable self.names will be?

Comment: @IbnuFirdaus, It become instance variable. Reading tutorial about classes ( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html ) will be helpful.